# how to sort the output by unsuccessful ping?

Tags: bash

I have a bash script that pings hosts from a file, the data is output as

```
Ping 1 - some-ip - ... which
Ping 2 - some-ip- ...successful
Ping 3 - some-ip - ...failure
Ping 4 - some-ip - ... failure
Ping 5 - some-ip - ...successful
Ping 6 - some-ip - ... failure
```

how do I make it so that only fail is output?

My script is below:

```
#!/bin/bash

hosts=/path/to/file


echo while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 || [ -n "$f2" ] ; do 
  echo -e -n "Pinging wg-ip $f1 - $f2 - ..."
  ping -f -W 2 -c 1 "$f2" &>/dev/null && echo success || echo fail
  echo -e -n "Pinging white-ip $f1 - $f4 - ..."
  ping -f -W 2 -c 1 "$f4" &>/dev/null && echo success || echo fail
done < <(tail -n +2 $hosts)
```

Comment: remove the `echo` commands you do not want ?

Comment: if I delete success, then all successful ones will also show fail

Comment: Could you simply grep for “failure”? Would that work for you…?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while IFS=';' read -r f1 f2 f3 f4 f5 f6 f7 f8 f9 || [ -n "$f2" ] ; do 
  echo -e -n "Pinging wg-ip $f1 - $f2 - ..."
  ping -f -W 2 -c 1 "$f2" &>/dev/null && echo success || echo fail
  echo -e -n "Pinging white-ip $f1 - $f4 - ..."
  ping -f -W 2 -c 1 "$f4" &>/dev/null && echo success || echo fail
done < <(tail -n +2 $centers) | grep fail
```